# Overwrite update and to_representation method throws AttributeError at POST request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to serialize fields from two models in a Onetofield relationship. So I overwrite the update and the to_representation method from the serializer.
For a GET request everything works fine, but a POST request throws a

AttributeError at /personalData/

'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'firstname'

Error.

My models:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    userData = models.OneToOneField(UserData)

    birthdate = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    jobTitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

My serializer class:

```
class EmployeePersonalDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    firstname = serializers.CharField()
    lastname = serializers.CharField()
    birthdate = serializers.CharField()
    gender = serializers.CharField()
    jobTitle = serializers.CharField()
    nationality = serializers.CharField()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.firstname = validated_data.get('firstname', instance.firstname)
        instance.lastname = validated_data.get('lastname', instance.lastname)
        instance.gender = validated_data.get('gender', instance.gender)
        instance.nationality = validated_data.get('nationality', instance.nationality)
        instance.employee.jobTitle = validated_data.get('jobTitle', instance.employee.jobTitle)
        instance.employee.birthdate = validated_data.get('birthdate', instance.employee.birthdate)
        instance.employee.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance


    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
                    'firstname': obj.firstname,
                    'lastname': obj.lastname,
                    'birthdate': obj.employee.birthdate,
                    'gender': obj.gender,
                    'jobTitle': obj.employee.jobTitle,
                    'nationality': obj.nationality
                }
```

**EDIT:**

The complete traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/myproject/views.py" in post
  177.             serializer.update(instance=userData, validated_data=serializer.data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  487.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  225.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
File "/myproject/serializers.py" in to_representation
  226.                     'firstname': obj.firstname,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /personalData/
Exception Value: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'firstname'
```

Comment: Please show the complete traceback.

Answer (score 1):

From DRF docs

> If you want to implement a **read-write** relational field, you must also
>   implement the .to_internal_value(self, data) method.

So, you want to implement a read-write(POST/GET) field, so you need to implement `.to_internal_value` method in your serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested serializers.  The error is saying that there is no firstname filed on employee, which there isn't.  You need a serializer for both the Employee and UserData.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue where I overwrote the `to_representation` and `create` method for the serializer.

In my case I forgot to add `serializer.save()` in my viewset. The issue got resolved after adding it.

The cause of the error was when I called the serializer in the viewset it passed the body of the POST request as `OrderedDict` to the obj in `to_representation` method.